# Password Attempt Limit and Disabling Accounts Without Creating a Security Hole

Tags: authentication, security

General security design question. Say you have a web app, an API, and a database. The API has a /login and the database has a user table with login info and an isActive column.

Given the requirement "Lock the user out after 5 password attempts (set isActive to false)" - how do you actually do that without opening yourself up to attackers? The only way I can think of is to create an API to the effect of /api/disable-account/{username} - but this has no auth and an attacker can just run through a list of usernames and disable peoples accounts. I could throttle the requests by IP, but a DDoS would get around that. How do you all approach this?

Thanks

Haven't implemented this yet as it's just a thought experiment.